# 5 V behaviour of Mikroe Feather click shield when powered from Feather only

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, step-down, schottky

The Mikroe Feather click shield supports a mode where the power comes from the Feather:

[image]

In this mode the Feather board will provide 5 V and 3.3 V labeled as `P5V` and `P3V3` respectively in the schematic below.

However I fail to see what will happen to the net labeled as `5V`.

Can someone explain how will the `5V` net reach 5 V when 5 V is input from `P5V`?

My reasoning has been annotated over the schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the daughter card is powered, I believe the feather board, P5V and P3v3 is brought down onto the main board.

U1 is an AND Gate IC, and the output is only high when both boards are powered via cables. therefore the net labeled "LOGIC" is low. So Q1 and Q2 are conducting. So, P3V3 feeds 3V3 via Q1, and P5V feeds 5V via D3 and Q2.

I don't completely understand what you are asking, but hopefully this clears it up.

If it doesn't let me know :)

Comment: But isn’t it that at first 5V is not fed and so U1 is not powered and so its output is undefined?

Comment: That's what I see as well, my guess though (since this is a working product?) is that either something isn't being shown in the image you have give, or there is another schematic, or there is enough leakage to GND the pin is tied down to some degree. If you have this, and a scope then just test during start up